# Why is a program with only atomics in SC-DRF but not in HRF-direct?

Tags: concurrency

In the paper "Heterogeneous-Race-Free Memory Models" [1], the authors state that a program consisting only of atomic is race free in SC-DRF but it is not in HRF-direct. I am not able to understand why this is. Can anyone explain how this can happen?

[1] Derek R. Hower *et al.*, "Heterogeneous-Race-Free Memory Models". In *Proceedings of ASPLOS '14*, ACM, 2014. ([PDF](http://research.cs.wisc.edu/multifacet/papers/asplos14_hrf_updated.pdf))

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Hopefully they didn't say explicitly say exactly "a program consisting only of atomics is race free in SC-DRF."  That's incorrect.

They do say that "[in] scoped synchronization ... it is possible to write a racey program that is composed entirely of atomics if those atomics do not use scopes correctly," [top of page 2], which is slightly different (and uses the word "racey" ambiguously, perhaps leading you to believe they meant the incorrect statement.)  They perhaps should have instead said said that in scoped synchronization it is possible to write a *non sequentially consistent* program that is composed entirely of atomics if those atomics do not use scopes correctly.

SC-DRF (roughly: the memory semantics for C++ and Java) divide memory locations into two classes, *synchronization* objects, (sometimes called `atomics`), and *data* objects.  For the most part  all operations on synchronization objects are guaranteed to be *sequentially consistent*.[1]  (*Not* race free.)  This is a constraint on the compiler, not the programmer.  It says that if the programmer says that one thread writes atomic object `a` then writes atomic object `b`, *all* the threads will see the writes occur in this order.  (The compiler is not allowed to reorder the accesses, and is required to insert the appropriate memory barriers and fences on machines that aren't sequentially consistent.)

*Sequentially consistent* means that all threads on all processors agree on a total order of all memory operations.  If one thread thinks that operation $x$ *happened before* operation $y$, *all* the threads think that operation $x$ *happened before* operation $y$.
Sequentially consistent does not mean *not racey* and it does not mean *deterministic*.  For example, two different threads could try to write the same synchronization variable at approximately the same time.  These accesses will be racey.  A sequentially consistent system will just guarantee that if one thread thinks that write $x$ happened before write $y$, *all* the threads will agree that write $x$ happened before write $y$.  Sequential consistency is useful because you can use it to construct and reason about useful non-deterministic synchronization objects like mutexes and condition variables.

SC-DRF then says that *if* your program is *data* race free, the operations on *data* objects will *appear* to be *sequentially consistent*.  The compiler *is* permitted to reorder (or even sometimes eliminate) operations on data objects, and if the underlying machine is not sequentially consistent, the compiler is not required to insert memory barriers or fences.  *But* the compiler is *not* allowed to reorder operations on data objects with respect to operations on synchronization objects.

*Data* race free is not the same as *race free*.  And *sequentially consistent* is not the same as *race free*.  A particular program execution schedule is *data* race free if for any pair of data object accesses, $x$ and $y$, by two different threads (at least one of which is a write operation) we can use the (sequentially consistent) order of atomic object accesses to prove that either $x$ *happened before* $y$ or $y$ *happened before* $x$.  If we can not do the proof then that execution schedule is *data racey*.

A *program* is *data race free* if all possible execution schedules are data race free.  A program is *data racey* if there is an execution schedule that is data racey.

Being *data race free* is a constraint on the programmer, not the compiler.  It says that if your program is data racey, then your program has no semantics.  The compiler is allowed to do anything it wants, including halting the program, going into an infinite loop, or blowing up the computer.

Oh dear.  **TL; DR!**  I haven't even mentioned SC-for-HRC yet!

In SC-for-HRC the atomics need to specify what *scope* they belong to.  Atomic accesses are guaranteed (by the compiler) to be sequentially consistent only within their own scope.  All threads within the scope will agree about the order in which the atomic accesses occur, but threads in a different scope may *not* agree (and may not even be able to see the accesses at all, let alone their order.)

For example it might be the case that all the GPU threads agree that thread 19 acquired mutex A then acquired mutex B, but all the CPU threads do *not* agree (or know) that thread 19 acquired mutex A or mutex B at all.  SC-DRF does not have "scopes" so doesn't suffer this problem.

[1] The exceptions to the sequentially consistent atomics have to do with explicitly using `std::memory_order_relaxed`.  So don't do that.  (And I'll ignore the exceptions in the rest of what I'm saying.)

Comment: Thank you for the succinct explanation of SC. This is the best I've read so far. I did not want it to end :)

Could you please also explain what "race free" is then, as you say it is different from data race free and SC?

Comment: "Race free" means that both your data and your synchronization are "race free", which means that your synchronization must be deterministic.  (A "race" is an ordering that is determined (resolved) by a non-deterministic process.)  There are deterministic synchronization systems (e.g. http://groups.csail.mit.edu/commit/papers/09/asplos073-olszewski.pdf) but they are unusual, and this isn't one.

Comment: Personally, I would prefer that nobody use the term "racey" or "race-free" with respect to synchronization operations.  I'd prefer that they used "non-deterministic" and "deterministic" for the resolution of who acquires a mutex.  And thus I'd prefer that the word "race" always be preceded by the word "data."

Comment: You say "_the compiler is not allowed to reorder operations on data objects with respect to operations on synchronization objects._" - Isn't the (C++) compiler (and CPU) allowed to reorder per the implicit acquire/release characteristics of SeqCst operations ?  (that is, reorder operations on data objects one-way with SeqCst stores and reorder them in opposite direction with SeqCst loads)

Comment: @LWimsey Yes, I think you are correct.  My answer was already too long, so I was imprecise with respect to acquire/release.